# Polygon Centroids working for only some Polygons in PyQGIS?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-3, centroids, pyqgis-3

I have a building Layer(Full of Polygons).I want to get centroids of polygons and save them as point layer.I am using python console within Qgis 3.0. I have tried below code.I got my Centroid Layer(but only for some polygon,not ALL).But I want the centroid for all Polygons.

```
vectorLyr=QgsVectorLayer("C:/Test/demand/Demand.shp", "BuildingLayer", "ogr")
vectorLyr.isValid()
import processing
processing.run("native:centroids", {'INPUT':'C:/Test/demand/Demand.shp','ALL_PARTS':False,'OUTPUT':'C:/Test/demand/centroid.shp'})
#{'OUTPUT': <qgis._core.QgsVectorLayer object at 0x000000000EF9C438>}
```

I am getting below error

```
traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.0\apps\Python36\lib\code.py", line 91, in   runcode
exec(code, self.locals)
File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.0/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\tools\general.py", line 84, in run
return Processing.runAlgorithm(algOrName, parameters, onFinish, feedback, context)
File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.0/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\core\Processing.py", line 190, in runAlgorithm
raise QgsProcessingException(msg)
_core.QgsProcessingException: There were errors executing the algorithm.
```

I have added visualization of my output
[image: centroid for some polygon,NOT FOR ALL]

Comment: Try to check validity of you polygons (vector -> geometry tools), maybe these polygons have invalid geometry?

Comment: What do you mean by Invalid Geometry ?

Comment: @Jane I checked some of them are wrong , but still for majority of them its not showing centroid

Comment: use v.clean from processing toolbox to clean topology. Zoom in to one without centroid and look through their vertices to understand what else with geometry of the polygon. - maybe duplicate vertices, self-intersections, etc.  QGIS centroid algorithm is very sensitive to initial geometry

Comment: @Jane I even tried that , but still not working. This is dropbox link please can you check . I can't proceed https://www.dropbox.com/sh/0kj4z0txefynfdf/AACfGXZvi-Mz3PAH-TxJ0ouFa?dl=0